# How to override the OAuth2AuthorizationServerSecurity's config?

Tags: spring-security

For [this project](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server).I want to build a OAuth2 Server on separate front-end and back-end architecture. The back-end based on [spring-authorization-server] while front-end based on VUE.

In the OAuth2 login flow ,it redirects to `/login` page, but i need to redirect to the vue front-end's login page such as "http://front-end ip:port/loginPage" .

How can I customize the `authenticationEntryPoint` in `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2AuthorizationServerSecurity` like this:

```
    .formLogin(withDefaults()).exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(xxx)
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** `OAuth2AuthorizationServerSecurity` has been removed. The code below is latest `master`.

The [sample authorization server](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server/blob/master/samples/boot/oauth2-integration/authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.java) application has the following default configuration:

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@Import(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.class)
public class AuthorizationServerConfig {

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("messaging-client")
                .clientSecret("secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .redirectUri("http://localhost:8080/authorized")
                .scope("message.read")
                .scope("message.write")
                .clientSettings(clientSettings -> clientSettings.requireUserConsent(true))
                .build();
        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public CryptoKeySource keySource() {
        return new StaticKeyGeneratingCryptoKeySource();
    }
}
```

In order to customize the default configuration, **DO NOT** `@Import(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.class)` and instead provide the following:

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class AuthorizationServerConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

        // TODO Customize http

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("messaging-client")
                .clientSecret("secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .redirectUri("http://localhost:8080/authorized")
                .scope("message.read")
                .scope("message.write")
.clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
                .build();
        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public CryptoKeySource keySource() {
        return new StaticKeyGeneratingCryptoKeySource();
    }
}
```

This provides you access to `HttpSecurity` so you can customize anything you require.